# How to create PostGIS template?

Tags: postgis, homebrew

I am following a tutorial to install pgrouting. However, I didn't get the part when it says

> Start pgAdmin and create a new database based on your **PostGIS template**

Where can I get this postgis template? I know I have installed PostGIS using homebrew. But I couldn't find the template. I am running macos now.

Comment: Which version of PostGIS are you using?

Answer (score 16):

**New Method With PostgreSQL 9.1**

Thanks to the advice of R.K. below, I took a look at [this tutorial](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26508/how-to-create-postgis-template) and found that for PostgreSQL 9.1 all you need to do is add the extensions `postgis` and `postgis_topology` to an existing database using the pgAdmin context menus. To create a postgis template, I created a new database called `template-postgis` and then added these extensions. I then created my other database using this template. When using `pg_dump` I found the size of the export was much smaller, as it seems to just include these lines and not dump the extension functions:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis WITH SCHEMA public;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis_topology WITH SCHEMA topology;
```

**Old Redundant Method:**

I ended up using the .sql files here:

```
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/share/contrib/postgis-2.0/postgis.sql
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/share/contrib/postgis-2.0/spatial_ref_sys.sql
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/share/contrib/postgis-2.0/topology.sql
```

Also, I got this error when I imported an existing PostGIS database into a new database made from this template:

```
ERROR:  type "spheroid" already exists
```

So I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/okfn/ckanext-spatial/blob/master/README.rst) and used `ON_ERROR_ROLLBACK=on` to set up the template, after creating a blank database called "template_postgis":

```
psql -U postgres -d template_postgis -1 -f /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/share/contrib/postgis-2.0/postgis.sql -v ON_ERROR_ROLLBACK=on
psql -U postgres -d template_postgis -1 -f /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/share/contrib/postgis-2.0/spatial_ref_sys.sql -v ON_ERROR_ROLLBACK=on
psql -U postgres -d template_postgis -1 -f /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/share/contrib/postgis-2.0/topology.sql -v ON_ERROR_ROLLBACK=on
```

And then imported my backup db, e.g.:

```
psql -U someuser -d somedb -1 -f somefile.sql -v ON_ERROR_ROLLBACK=on
```

**Even Older Method:**

I did this:

```
createdb -E UTF8 -T template0 template_postgis
createlang -d template_postgis plpgsql
psql --quiet -d template_postgis -f /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/share/extension/postgis--2.0.1.sql
```

The path to `postgis--2.0.1.sql` will be different depending on your setup.

Comment: To complete your answer (which works on my Mac): on a Mac, if you installed postgis from Kyngchaos ports, the postgis installation file is: /usr/local/pgsql/share/extension/postgis--2.0.1.sql

Comment: For the newest method, is 'SCHEMA' needed? What's it for? (Yours is the only example I've seen so far that do that.)

Answer (score 15):

If you are running PostgreSQL 9.1+, you [don't need to bother with the template database](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgis_tut01). Just create a database and then on the SQL view in pgAdmin, type and run

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

That will spatially enable your database.

Comment: Can the template method still be used?  Or, is there a way that to add this info to the "new database" dialog in pgAdminIII?

Comment: you probably also want to add `CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;`

Comment: @monkut in pgAdmin4 this is available via right-click on 'Extensions' in the navigation tree

Comment: `CREATE EXTENSION` needs superuser privileges, so actually creating/using a template might be very good idea.

Answer (score 3):

in fact this is the foundation of postgis installation.

if you have postgis template you can create a new database from it as :

```
 createdb -T postgistemplate -O gis gisdb
```

if you not have it, you can do this with this way:

```
sudo su postgres
createdb postgistemplate
createlang plpgsql postgistemplate
psql -d postgistemplate -f /usr/share/postgresql-8.2-postgis/lwpostgis.sql
psql -d postgistemplate -f /usr/share/postgresql-8.2-postgis/spatial_ref_sys.sql
```

you can use bash scripts Debian/Ubuntu - create_template_postgis-debian.sh, [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_downloads/create_template_postgis-debian.sh)

i hope it helps you...

Comment: It is probably the case that the user `postgres` does not have permissions to use a terminal, in which case the `sudo su postgres` command will silently fail. To get past this you can precede all these commands with `sudo -u postgres` to run the command as the postgres user without switching to the postgres user.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember there is some script available for the workshop to create those template databases. It's also available here: https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting-contrib/blob/master/scripts/create_templates.sh

Eventually you need to change a few things here and there, because it was written to work for Debian/Ubuntu. But you can just pick what you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/sh
instance_name=$1
psql << EOF
create database $instance_name;
\connect $instance_name
-- Enable PostGIS (includes raster)
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
-- Enable Topology
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
-- fuzzy matching needed for Tiger
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
-- Enable US Tiger Geocoder
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_tiger_geocoder;
EOF
```

I use this bash script to execute creation of new database with postgis enabled and name given on stdin.

Postgres 9.3

PostGIS 2.1.3